# How to check if a stripe payment token has been used

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The standard way to invoke a Stripe payment is through their recommended html form via a `POST` request.

**From the docs:**

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="my_key"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

This generates a `$_POST['stripeToken']`, a one-time token used to verify the payment. Once this token is used. It can't be used again.

Oh the **php backend**, the charge is handled like this:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 2000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'], // created by the form above
  "description" => "Charge for some product"
));
```

**The Problem:**

The issue is that if I refresh the resulting page, the form is resubmitted and an expired token exception is detected - because the one-time token is posted for a second time.

**The Question:**

Is there a way to detect ahead of time whether the token has been used (before the charge object is created)? Or is it better practice to redirect to a new page after the payment logic completes, so that if a user refreshes the page, the form won't be resubmitted again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Token [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) has the `used` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-used) which gives you this information. You could simply call the Retrieve Token [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) to confirm this information.

This is likely the wrong approach though. Instead you should prevent this situation from happening. The best option is to redirect your customer to a different page after the charge creation so that reloading the page does not re-submit the form data incorrectly.